# Jquery Ajax call to java rest api success function is not firing

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send HTML form data as a JSON to java rest api and it generates response as JSON.
**Here is my code.**

**HTML FORM:**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action ="" method= "post" name= "testform">
    <p> Balance : <input type="text" id="balance" name="balance" /></p>
    <p>Pin : <input type="text" id="pin" name="pin" /></p>
    <p>CardID : <input type="text"  id="cardId" name="cardId" /></p>
    <input type ="submit" id="add-account" value="add user"></input>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery CODE:**

```
$(function(){
console.log("Jquery called");
$('#add-account').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var balance = $("#balance").val();
    var pin = $("#pin").val();
    var cardId = $("#cardId").val();
    var firstcall = 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8081/quickpay/webapi/myresource",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "balance":balance,
            "pin": pin,
            "cardId": cardId
        }), 
        dataType: "json",
        success:function (successResponse,textStatus,jqXHR) {
            alert("first api");         
        },
        error: function (errorResponse1) {
            console.log(errorResponse1);
            alert("failed first api");
        }
    });
});
});
```

**JAVA REST API:**

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Account createAccount(Account acc){
        Account account =  AccountService.createAccount(acc.getBalance(),acc.getPin(),acc.getCardId());
        return account;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT I'm getting is:**

When I try to call the api in POSTMAN, it runs successfully and data is inserted successfully.
When I try to click on ADD USER button , data is inserted into database successfully but ***ALERT messege of success function does not appear.***

I'm monitoring network tab of Google chrome, **There I find this error in myresource status is cancelled and type is xhr.**

When hovering mouse on Jquery.min.js I get this..

n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send   @   jquery.min.js:4

n.extend.ajax   @   jquery.min.js:4

(anonymous function)    @   main.js:9

n.event.dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3

n.event.add.r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3

**Problem  : How can I make success function of ajax call working ?? Where I'm going wrong.?**

**EDIT:**
I added preventDefault() method. So Now It is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not cancel the button click so the form submits

```
$('#add-account').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefaul();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Bro!
I have tried using preventDefault() method before but it didn't work.
but Now it is firing success funcion!